# Ember data DS.JSONAPIAdapter pagination

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am working on a project using EmberJS 2.1 and EmberData 2.1.

Everything is good but seems I am not able to understand how can I paginate results from the API.

Current response that I get from the API:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "user",
      "attributes": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "company": "Google",
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Mr.",
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      },
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "type": "user",
      "attributes": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "company": "Google",
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Mr.",
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      },
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "type": "user",
      "attributes": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "company": "Google",
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Mr.",
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      },
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "type": "user",
      "attributes": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "company": "Google",
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Mr.",
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      },
      "id": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my route looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});
```

Is there any resource where I can learn how to implement pagination? I've found a lot of tutorials, but they're for DS.RESTAdapter.

The API was built with Spring MVC.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't used it but I read this bit in the guides recently http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/handling-metadata/

Comment: it looks like you'd pull from meta key in your response http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-meta

Comment: Does the API support pagination? Does it provide any metadata like how many users there are?

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement pagination is to make sure your API is returning metadata relating to the request. You need the count of results returned in the response, and the total number of resource available. It also needs to be able to respond to query paramaters for page[offset] and page[limit] so it knows which results to send back to you.

Ember side - you will need to have a query parameter for pageLimit and pageOffset, the offset needs to be calculated by you depending on how many records are in your store and sent to the server as part of the request so it knows from where to start giving you back data. The limit is just the number of results you want back each time.

Answer (score 0):

We are using same libraries and there are 2 alternatives that may come immediatelly handy:

- take advantage of already implemented solutions, say ember-addons supporting pagination, quick link:
  https://www.emberaddons.com/?query=pagination
- implement it on your own, if what you need is a too custom solution. In this case I would recommend creating a query object as you need and pass it to the `store.query("user", query)`, which, supporting out-of-the-box, parses meta-data that could be used for example: to distinguish whether there is anything more to be loaded.
  I wrote a small rough snippet, please excuse any typos:

  ```
  // users controller
  modelName: "user",

  pageSize: 10,
  ```

  // pageLimit: 50, pageOffset: 0, ...

  ```
  queryObject: Ember.computed("pageSize",/* more props ,*/ function(){
   const queryObject = {};
   const pageSize = this.get("pageSize");

  //... validate pageSize and currentPage values, are they numbers, positive numbers, whatever.....

   queryObject.page = {
    page: pageSize
   };

   return queryObject;
  }),

  ....

  actions{
   fetchPage(pageIndex){
    // check pageIndex....

    // retrieve actual queryObject
    const queryObject = this.get("queryObject");

    // set which batch we are going to load now, "cursor" is just an example, depends what your backend expects
    queryObject.page.cursor = pageIndex;

    // query records
    return this.store.query(this.get("modelName"), queryObject)
     .then(/*...do sth with fetched records, update model, retrieve metadata...*/)
     .catch(/*...take care of error...*/);
   }
  }
  ```